# apache load css file as text/html

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache-2.4

This is my site

```
http://jiyihezi.net/
```

The css and js file content type is `text/html`, So browser can not load them.

But if I open this following link,

```
http://210.73.222.16/memorybox-web
```

The css and js file all loaded ok.

So I try to enable `mime` module and `header`, Then I try to:

#### add following line to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
...
```

#### change my virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/memorybox-web/
  ServerName jiyihezi.net
  <Directory /var/www/memorybox-web/>
  <Files *.css>
    Header set Content-type "text/css"
  </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restart my apache, And open browser again, but still can not load css file and js file.

Comment: I think the real problem is that they're 404s. http://jiyihezi.net/memorybox-web/static/css/bootstrap.min.css http://jiyihezi.net/memorybox-web/static/css/all.css

Comment: but these files are  exist

Comment: Then you've goofed something up in your configs.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why this happens. For me, I mistakenly make apache to process `css` file as it does with php.

```
<FilesMatch \.(php|css)$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

So I need to remove `css` from `FilesMatch` to make the server treat `css` file as it normally does.

```
<FilesMatch \.(php)$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```